# How do I return all rows from Azure mobile Service Get Request?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

So I have a `Azure Mobile Web Service` which returns rows from my database.

But currently it doesn't return all rows and seems to be capped.

From [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#paging) I read the quote:

> **Paging considerations for a .NET backend mobile service**
>
> To override the 50 row limit in a .NET backend mobile service, you
>   must also apply the EnableQueryAttribute to the public GET method and
>   specify the paging behavior. When applied to the method, the following
>   sets the maximum returned rows to 1000:
>
> ```
> [EnableQuery(MaxTop=1000)]
> ```

This is good and returns 1000 instead of the default 50.

Is there a way to return all rows rather than a set number using the [EnableQueryAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute.aspx)?

Comment: Would setting the attribute to int.MaxValue work (i.e., `[EnableQuery(MaxTop = int.MaxValue)]`? This would essentially mean the return of everything. You should be aware of the memory implications of this on the server, though, as the response may be buffered before returned to the client (not sure about this behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the property in that attribute to `int.MaxValue` (i.e., [EnableQuery(MaxTop = int.MaxValue)]`, then you'll get the behavior you want.

Another way is to not return an `IQueryable`, to which the `MaxTop` behavior is applied, but to return an `IList` instead (but you'll lose the other `IQueryable` features, such as filtering):

```
    public IList<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
        return Query().ToList();
    }
```

Notice that you should be aware of the memory implications of returning a very large number of items. I'm not sure, but it's possible that the entire response is buffered before it's returned to the client (you should test that), and if you return a very large number of elements, you may run into performance issues in the server.